# Skip json elements deserialization on condition

Tags: c#, json, serialization, windows-runtime, json.net

have the following problem. There is a bunch of quite large json objects which I need to have as objects. But there are conditions, when I actually don't need some of them, for example, if one of inner fields is "isDeleted:true". For now I have to first automatically through JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<..>(stringJson) all the array of data and then choose in filter necessary. What I'd like to achieve is to skip some whole elements when condition isn't true. Are there any ways to achieve this beside manual conversion?

UPDATE:
json looks something like this:

```
{
  results:[
     around 20 fields here with inner objects,
     isDeleted:"true",
     user:{
        another dozen of fields
     },
     images:[{..},{..}]
 ]}
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: It is possible at serialization because it is hard to modify the created json string manually, but it is simple at deserialization. Check your condition and assign default values to some properties. BTW: Why do you want to do it. Do you expect some performance gain?

Comment: EZI, yes, I'd really like to gain some performance and make less operations as it's a mobile app. What do you mean it's simple? Manual deserialization? I agree it's not really hard, it's just manual populating of every single field and inner objects that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, [`JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader.htm):

> Represents a reader that provides fast, non-cached, forward-only access to serialized JSON data.

Thus, in order to skip deleted items when deserializing a collection, you're going to need to read the JSON for each collection entry into memory *somehow* in order to check the `isDeleted` property.  If your collection item class is so heavy that you don't want to create one when not absolutely required, you could use a custom `JsonConverter` to load each entry into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) container, then check that for  `isDeleted`:

```
public class DeletetedItemSkippingCollectionConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<T>);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (existingValue as List<T>);
        if (list == null)
            list = new List<T>();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            return list;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                break;
            var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
            var deleted = obj["isDeleted"];
            if (deleted != null)
            {
                if (deleted.Type == JTokenType.Boolean && (bool)deleted)
                    continue;
            }
            if (obj != null)
            {
                list.Add((T)obj.ToObject<T>(serializer));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then apply that to any `List<T>` property you want to filter:

```
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject()
    {
        this.ResultList = new List<Item>();
    }

    [DataMember(Name="results")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DeletetedItemSkippingCollectionConverter<Item>))]
    public List<Item> ResultList { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could load each item in the collection into its "final" representation, check it for being deleted, and dispose of it if so.  Assuming your objects all implement an interface `IsDeleted`, you could do:

```
public interface IIsDeleted
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; }  // Corresponds it "isDeleted" property in the JSON.
}

public class IsDeletetedItemSkippingCollectionConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : IIsDeleted
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<T>);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (existingValue as List<T>);
        if (list == null)
            list = new List<T>();
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            return list;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                break;
            var obj = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
            if (obj == null || obj.IsDeleted)
            {
                var disposable = obj as IDisposable;
                if (disposable != null)
                    disposable.Dispose();
                continue;
            }
            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: a) many `JObject.Load`s to check  `isDeleted`, Will this be more performant?  b) `isDeleted` may be the last property, so false result is possible with this approach.

Comment: @EZI - poster would need to test performance.  Since his/her class contains images, it may be better to load to an intermediate representation rather than actually creating the image in unmanaged memory.  But see the alternative I just added.

Comment: @EZI - how is a false result possible?

Comment: **a)** Although OP is interested in performance, you say *"I can post any answer, OP should check it"*. At least say some words, stating why this might be more performant **b)** There is no such thing (with Json.Net) to directly deserialize to Image **c)** I am too lazy to prepare a code just to show someone's answer is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I think it doesn't solve anything as I still need to parse all the array items to check the property. I thought may be the was a way to check without deserialization of other properties, but as far as I see -- the reader can go only forward so I won't be able to search for it in root to check and then decide whether to go to next array element or to parse this whole one, too.